# code comment on question inserting character

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I am trying to add a comment with a regex code snippet to a question but the comment keeps ending up with a strange characters being inserted in the posted comment.

The regex snippet is:

```
(?=^.{1,255}$)(^(((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}|(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-))$)
```

I paste it in surrounded by ` (grave) for code snippet in comments - however, I noticed the code wasn't working if I copied and pasted it out of the comments and the reason was (after looking at the html source) 2 characters keeps getting inserted into the string. You will see the HTML source for the comment is: (note the odd characters inserted):

```
(?=^.{1,255}$)(^(((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?&lt;!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}|(?!-)[a-zA-Z0&zwnj;&#8203;-9-]{1,63}(?&lt;!-))$)
```

Comment: `(?=^.{1,255}$)(^(((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}|(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-))$)`

Comment: yeah, just copying and pasting the 1st code snippet above as a comment (inside a pair of `) ends up with the weird character inserted - look at html source.

Comment: That is our [StackExchange™ WhiteSpace EnforcementOfficer™](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91512/220538). It is not a bug. See this MSE post: [Occasionally, the Unicode character sequence U+200C U+200B (ZWNJ ZWSP) is inserted into comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170970/220538)

Comment: huh. that is interesting. I would say it kind of IS a bug since it means code snippets in comments will fail for many use cases without any visible reason, although I see that for formatting reasons it is necessary. thanks though.

Comment: You're not supposed to post long code snippets in comments, so a feature that impacts them is probably not going to be considered a bug. At worst it could be considered a necessary evil.

Comment: while I agree with you - I don't think a single snippet of regex over 80 characters (such as above) should be considered inappropriate for a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anna Murali mentioned, this is by design to enforce word wrap on long (~ >= 80 char) code snippets. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171065/262550 for more information on why this decision was made. It can be inconvenient in the rare case (such as your regex example), but it does much more good than harm.

Comment: Perhaps a warning could be displayed via js if it will apply to a comment. I think that will save a lot of confusion, because it took me a while to figure out why the comment wasn't working when copy&pasted.

Comment: That's a good point. Feel free to suggest a feature request for this (I'd also include discussion tag) and we'll see what people think!

Comment: done - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262554/display-a-warning-when-editing-a-comment-when-the-unicode-sequence-u200c-u200b